# Does pycassa's ColumnFamily.get_indexed_slices return a generator?

Tags: python, indexing, nosql, cassandra, pycassa

The documentation at [1] says that `ColumnFamily.get_range()` returns a python generator over `(key, {column_name: column_value})`. I wonder if  `ColumnFamily.get_indexed_slices()` also returns a generator.

The documentation is a bit unclear about that.

[1] http://pycassa.github.com/pycassa/api/pycassa/columnfamily.html#pycassa.columnfamily.ColumnFamily.get_indexed_slices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I realized it is a generator.

```
>>> col_fam.get_indexed_slices(clause)
<generator object get_indexed_slices at 0x1fdcf00>
```

Comment: If you're OK with your answer, accept it, pretty sure you get a badge for that :-)